# Opencv4Android: How to use with C++

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying too build a samples which using opencv for android. Here is my C++ code:

- Header file:

  ```
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif
  #include "jni.h"
  #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
  namespace openCVFuncs
  { 
      cv::Mat contrastFilter(cv::Mat inputMatm, float contrastValue);
  }
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  ```
- Cpp file:

  ```
  namespace openCVFuncs
  {
      cv::Mat contrastFilter(cv::Mat inputMat, float contrastValue)
      {
          contrastValue = pow(2,contrastValue);
          cv::Mat outMat = inputMat.clone();
          uchar* data_img_in=(uchar*)inputMat.data;
          uchar* data_img_out=(uchar*)outMat.data;
          int temp = 0;
          for(int i=0;i<inputMat.size().height;i++)
              for(int j=0;j<inputMat.size().width;j++)
                  for (int c=0;c<inputMat.channels();c++)
                  {
                     temp = (data_img_in+inputMat.step[0]*i)[j*inputMat.channels()+c];                       
                      temp = (int)((temp - 128.0) * contrastValue) +128;
                      if (temp < 5) temp = 5;
                      if (temp > 255) temp = 255;                       
                      (data_img_out+outMat.step[0]*i)[j*outMat.channels()+c]  = temp;
                  }
          return outMat;
      };
  }
  ```

And I got many errors like that :

> /opt/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/valarray_before.h:652:3: error: template with C linkage

What wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an "extern C"-block, you can only use the things that are available to C, so that rules out function overloading/polymorphism, namespaces, amongst other things.

In the header file you posted you include a .hpp file (which could possibly include one of the unusable definitions) and define a namespace.

This page gives some nice pointers on the subject on what you can and cannot do and how you can wrap calls to C++ namespaces / overloaded functions for use in a library compiled by a C compiler, see "Accessing C++ Code from Within C Source":

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mixingcandcpluspluscode-305840.html